# Is netlink socket a client/server mode?

Tags: c, linux, netlink

Now I am meeting a trouble:My netlink is used for kernel and user space communication. When I only start the user space's netlink socket, it will give me an error:

> proctol not supported

My source code is:

```
if((sk_fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, netlink_id)) == -1)
    {
        printf("socket error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
```

which `netlink_id` is 1567. But when I start the kernel netlink in advance, it will work well.
So I think the netlink is a c/s model. Do you agree with me?

Comment: please specify what you mean by 'c/s model'. Be explicit. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Yeah, Client/Server model.

Comment: I have tried many times for the question, I used netlink for communication between kernel and user's space.The netlink socket in kernel must start first, and then start the user's. When you do as this , you will use netlink successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question, I have tried many ways to test.Now I had a conclusion: When we used netlink for communication between kernel and user's space, you must create netlink in kernel first and started success, the netlink socket in user's space could only create success. So the communication could only establish success when you did above well.